# Getting an Error While Setting Up a Parse Server on AWS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to figure this out for the last several weeks and I tried everything but with no avail. If somebody could PLEASE give me some suggestions on how to make this work, that would mean soooooo much.

**This is my problem:**

I am following this blog: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk. I think I followed all the steps correctly but I am not seeing my object being upload to Mongo.

**Here is what I've done so far:**

On my Parse dashboard, I copied my Application ID:
[image]

To my AWS software configuration:
[image]

Then, I copied the Application ID and put it in my `AppDelegate.swift` like so:

`ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "applicationId"`

Then, on my Parse dashboard, I copied my master key:
[image]

Then, I copied it to the property value on my AWS software configuration: 
[image]

Then, I copied the Master Key and put it in my `AppDelegate.swift` like so:

`ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "my master key"'.

Then, I copied my MongDB URI, including my own account and password:
[image]

And put it in my AWS software configuration[image]

Then, I copied the URL on top my AWS dashboard and put it in my `AppDelegate.swift` like so:

`ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "myServerURL/parse"`.

**Here's the problem:**
When I run this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
    testObject["foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
        print("Object has been saved.")
    }
}
```

I get this error: 
`2016-04-03 15:32:19.113 ParseStarterProject-Swift[15395:161311] [Error]: {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.12.0)` Though, it says `Object has been saved`, the object is not showing up on Mongo. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that, when you use your MongoDB URI, you put your USERNAME and PASSWORD related to that Database! It`s not the username and password to your mongoDB account. After creating a database on MongoDB, you have to create a user for that database and then put them on MongoDB URI

And your function will always call "object has been saved" because you`re not checking the success boolean.

```
if success{
 print("Object has been saved.")
}
```

Comment: Sandor, thank you sooooo much for your response. I made sure that my USERNAME and PASSWORD is related to that Database. But it still has not been working. Any other thing that I should check?